# Bootstrap-4 scripts best location and scripts' tags

Tags: bootstrap-4, deferred-loading

An old topic with lots of discussions...
I read many of them but still not sure...

What is the best place and best script's tags (defer/async) to locate the bootstrap-4 JS scripts for the best performance?

In Bootstrap documentation: "Place the following s near the end of your pages,right **before** the body closing tag

```html
</body>
```

They don't use any script tags (defer/async)

I read about the scripts tags,
Some wrote that locating the script before the body closing tag is like locating the heading with "defer" tag. (except for the old browsers)
some say "performance would be better if the scripts are still at the end, as they will be downloaded later"

So is the following the best practice ???

Locating jquery/popper/bootstrap before the body closing tag, jquery first and using defer to popper.min.js and to bootstrap.min.js?

```html
<body>
......
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Or just doing as in the bootstrap documentation without the "defer" tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put at the end is the best practice, you can even write script after the close of the body: an html is loaded from the top to the button, when a browser reach a script element it downloads (and wait) the source, so if you put it at the end, the page will load and then the js will downloaded. Remember that js is needed to make the view dynamic so until the page is loaded you don't need functionalities like: click on a dropdwon and see its content. Defer/async are just a way to achieve the same result, but it's not exactly the same.

Comment: I assume you mean to put at the end without the "defer" ?

Comment: So generally it is better to put any script, that the page doesn't use when loading, at the end instead of the beginning (on the head) with defer/async?

Comment: it depends, put a script in the head section (without async) force page to download the script (if not cached) so it wastes time and user may starts to think that the app doens't work. Nowadays we use min version of js file and networking performance are not a problem. When you put a script at the end the page is rendered quickly and user has to wait until the js are loaded only to use their functionalities, but download fex MBs is fast.

Comment: Thanks GJCode :), This is clear but between the options Head+defer/async or  Body end without defer/async?

Comment: Body without defer :)

Comment: @GJCode It use to be but no longer is best practice. Learning is constant adaptation

Answer (score 1):

## Head is for external resources

To have all dependencies out of the way at the start of the document is best practice. The `<head>` was made for exactly that. As the DOM is not loaded at that moment in page loading, this will fail all references to the DOM made there. There used to be a (dark) time, before defer, where it was common to get the advice to place the script-includes after `</body>` but before `</html>`.

But if the script resources are indeed loaded in the header, there are some better solutions to deal with this:

### Eventhandler

One trick is to wait for the DOM to be loaded with an `DOMContentloaded` [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). The event will fire as soon as the DOM is loaded and ready. This could be combined with `async` to speed the perceived speed of the page loading.

### Defer

Since quite some time it is possible to postpone execution of the JavaScript till after the page is loaded. The attribute `defer` on the `script src=` will queue the JavaScripts in order of reference.

### Async

The attribute `async` will not necessarily execute the script after the page is loaded, it simply suggests to the browser *not* to wait for download and execution of the JavaScript (block) but instead perform it in parallel with page rendering. There is no guarantee in load order.

This will work fine for business logic in JavaScript that does not directly depend on the page content or other resources. (https://javascript.info/script-async-defer). Including `bootstrap.min.js` with `async` will most likely fail to produce the expected result.

### WordPress

At the moment, but that might very well change, without trickery WordPress will not defer JavaScripts. You can rely on plugins to do that or [add a simple function](https://kinsta.com/blog/defer-parsing-of-javascript/#functions) to your functions.php

### Inline JavaScript

In case the JavaScript is not read from a `src` file but directly included `defer` and `async` will be ignored. If inline JavaScript needs to wait for the DOM to be loaded either use the event listener or indeed place the `<script></script>` after  but before  (Most browsers are fine if the code is after `<html>`. html5 the `<html>`-tag is in practice optional)

## Bootstrap

To answer your question: To me it is unclear why Bootstrap does not use or document the use of defer for their scripts. They, finally, even got rid of depending on jQuery so I can see no reason why they still [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template) it like that.